# If the operations can be done in any order, how many different ways of completing the manufacturing are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question: In a sheet metal operation, three notches and four
bends are required. If the operations can be done in any order,
how many different ways of completing the manufacturing are
possible?

While the answer solution says 35, I am having trouble understanding how to apply to combination formula to this question. I know there are 7 operations total which makes n = 7. However, the selection size is also 7, which shouldn't also make k = 7 as well?

Comment: You need to select which three of the seven operations will be notches or, equivalently, which four of the seven operations will be bends.  Therefore, $k \neq 7$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your $n$ and $k$ are, but we can think of the problem in this way. Let $N$ denote a notch and $B$ denote a bend. How many ways can we put 3 $N$'s and 4 $B$'s in $7$ slots?
$$
\text{__} \; \text{__} \; \text{__} \; \text{__} \; \text{__} \; \text{__} \; \text{__} \;
$$
Here is one way:
$$
\text{N} \; \text{N} \; \text{N} \; \text{B} \; \text{B} \; \text{B} \; \text{B} \;
$$
In order to count the total number of ways, think of how many ways we can place the first $N$, then the second $N$, and then the third $N$. Do we need to account for the $B$'s afterwards? Does this remind you of any formulas you might have learned?

Now this more abstract formulation is essentially the same as your problem; each sequence of $N$'s and $B$'s gives us a different manufacturing order.

Comment: So the first N has 7 spots, the second N has 6, and the third N has 5. There are 3 N's selected so we can divide 7! by 4! to get rid of the unnecessary placeholders. I know that we aren't supposed to account for the B's afterward but can't seem to think of why; is it because we can treat them like the "background"?

Comment: You started on the right track. We have 7 spots, 6 spots, 5 spots to place the $N$'s, which gives $7 \times 6 \times 5$. Now this assumes the $N$'s are ordered (think of placing $N_1, N_2, N_3$, so that $N_1 N_2 N_3$ is different from $N_3 N_2 N_1$ for example). However, we specifically want to just place generic $N$'s that are indistinguishable. Given a placement of the three distinct $N$s, we can arrange them in $3! = 6$ ways. Therefore, the total number of ways to place $N$'s is $(7 \times 6 \times 5) / 6 = 35$. Indeed, the $B$'s are just in the background and are determined by the $N$'s.

Comment: To give a formula that answers this question (which might link up with the notation you are learning), the answer would be $\binom{7}{3} = \frac{7!}{3! 4!} = \frac{7 \times 6 \times 5}{6}$ - read "seven choose three". (This should make sense given our derivation.)